# Slack bot send an image by Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a slackbot which takes images from the Amazon S3 bucket and posts it to a slack channel. I made sure that the Amazon S3 bucket is public. Here's my code :

```
 const slackToken = SLACK_TOKEN;
 const url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage';
 const res =  await axios.post(url, {
   channel: '#general',
   blocks: [
   
     {
       type: 'image',
       image_url: AWS_S3_BUCKET_URL,
       alt_text: 'qrcode'
     }
     
   ],
   username: 'SlackBot',
 }, { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${slackToken}` } });

 console.log('Done', res.data);
```

But it gives me this wierd error

```
  ok: false,
  error: 'invalid_blocks',
  errors: [ 'downloading image failed [json-pointer:/blocks/0/image_url]' ],
  response_metadata: {
    messages: [
      '[ERROR] downloading image failed [json-pointer:/blocks/0/image_url]'
    ]
  }
}
```

When I replace the AWS_S3BUCKET_URL with any other url like `https://mms.businesswire.com/media/20200513005022/en/791013/22/AWS_logo_RGB.jpg`
It works fine, But gives error in case of AWS_S3_BUCKET_URL.

Comment: What is AWS_S3_BUCKET_URL ?

Comment: `https://screenshots-aws-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/9.png`
@AnonCoward

Comment: You're passing an image of the AWS logo as a qr-code?  I'm confused.

Comment: Basically its a screenshot from a google login page,that I uploaded to s3 bucket using my scripts, now I'm trying to post it to a slack channel @AnonCoward

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well. In my case, the images in question had the metadata `Content-Encoding: base64`.

Also, make sure you have your bucket CORS policy set to allow slack:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://*.slack.com",
            "https://*.slack-edge.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```